# login.php:170 Uncaught ReferenceError: user_register is not defined at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (login.php:170) onclick @ login.php:170

Tags: javascript, php, html

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KxzRN.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eC47w.png)
hey the register button is not responding of this code can anybody help me fix it. it shows this error in the cosole.
login.php:170 Uncaught ReferenceError: user_register is not defined

1. List item

at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (login.php:170)
onclick @ login.php:170

Comment: [Please no images of code](https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode)

Comment: please help me solve this errorlogin.php:170 Uncaught ReferenceError: user_register is not defined
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (login.php:170)
onclick @ login.php:170

Comment: Help us help you. Edit your question, put your code inline, format it, read [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). If you expect people to spend time to help you, you can't simply dump a link to a screenshot of code.

Comment: Modify your question, add more information and paste your code also.

Answer (score 0):

Add this line to the end of the .js file that contains your function:

```
window.yourFunction = yourFunction;
```

Answer (score -1):

You should define the button in javascipt file on .onclick() function